# Proper Naming Convention for Cocoa Base Classes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, naming-conventions

I have an app where I subclass UIViewController and add some characteristics to it, then use it for every viewcontroller within my app. I was just wondering what is the naming convention for this? I've called it UIDefaultViewController, but I was wondering if there is someway I can also name it UIViewController, or if there is a proper naming convention for this? I also have my own implementations of UITextView and some other common UI classes and was just wondering how to name them when they're the primary version of their parent class that I'm using within my app.

Comment: Can you use a [category](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/occategories.html)?  That would let you use the `UIViewController` name.

Comment: nah i need to override the initializer, i dont think you can do that with a category can you? prob better that I don't.

Comment: Sure, you can override any method.  You just can't add instance variables.  You can, however, fake them pretty convincingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should definitely not use the "UI" prefix. It's reserved for classes from UIKit.framework. I would suggest coming up with your own prefix (initials, company initials, something like that) and using that instead. So I might have CFMViewController, say.

Comment: Thanks. So is it better to use the initials for all of my UI elements, or should I just use them with baseclasses like CFMViewController but if I need to extend off that, do I do CFMTranslucentViewController? or just TranslucentViewController. I'm so anal about this type of stuff.

Comment: I've seen people use their initials to prepend Cocoa class names, as in CHDataStructures: http://cocoaheads.byu.edu/code/CHDataStructures.  However, that's usually done when in libraries to avoid name collisions with application code.  If I were you, I'd call it `BaseViewController`.  That's just my opinion though.

Comment: Although I could be wrong.  Apple's documentation says to use prefixes:  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001281-BBCHBFAH

Comment: It's best to approach this from the point of view of "what is going to happen if I don't do this?". The answer to that is "if you pick something so generic that someone else *also* picks it, then it's undefined which class you'll actually get". Note that "someone else" can include iOS itself, either with a private class, or in any future version of the OS. So, the takeaway here is "pick something unique, hence the prefix. Other than that it only matters for your own clarity".

Answer (score 2):

This is fairly common, I think. I do it a lot in my apps, I always call it `BaseViewController`. For `UITextView` and such, I think `BaseTextView` or something makes sense. It's really up to you and what you feel describes it well. I call it a "Base" because you subclass all of your other view controllers from this.

I wouldn't call it `UIDefaultViewController` because the UI prefix means it is a part of the SDK. I would prefer something like `DefaultUIViewController` over that.